# Strategy to preserve SNS topic subscriptions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I'm using terraform to create a topic, subscribe an SQS queue to that topic, and then subscribe a lambda to that queue. The terraform for each resource is kept in separate repos with different terraform state. While it should be rare, whenever the topic is destroyed by terraform and subsequently recreated by terraform, the subscription is broken.

You would think running plan-apply on the terraform that owns the queue would resubscribe the queue, but it doesn't (0 changes). It remains in a broken state where no subscriptions are listed on the topic, and no messages are transmitted to the queue. You then need to fully destroy the terraform that owns the queue, and now the lambda that was subscribed to it must also be destroyed and recreated. This is tedious and fragile.

Are there any strategies for keeping the subscription active, or auto recreating it when the terraform for it lives in another repo? Logically, it seems that the `aws_sns_topic_subscription` hasn't been destroyed, and the queue should still be linked to the topic via the arn, but there must be some underlying reference that hooks them together instead.